# No instance for Control.Monad.Logger.MonadLogger when attempting to use persistent

Tags: database, haskell, web-applications, logging, persistent

I'm building a web app using `scotty` and `persistent` and having some troubles compiling. This is my code:

```
runDb :: SqlPersist (ResourceT IO) a -> IO a
runDb query = runResourceT . withSqliteConn "dev.app.sqlite3" . runSqlConn $ query

readMessage :: KeyBackend (PersistEntityBackend Post) Post -> IO (Maybe Post)
readMessage postID = runDb $ get postID
```

And I get this error message:

```
Message.hs:30:30:
No instance for (Control.Monad.Logger.MonadLogger IO)
  arising from a use of `get'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (Control.Monad.Logger.MonadLogger IO)
In the second argument of `($)', namely `get postID'
In the expression: runDb $ get postID
In an equation for `readMessage':
    readMessage postID = runDb $ get postID
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448206/yesod-exitfailure-1-when-installing-scaffolded-app) question, but the accepted answer is use an old version of `monad-logger` which would also force me to use old versions of many other packages, `scotty` and `persistent` included, and I don't want to do that. The other answer recommends using `runNoLoggingT`, which I was unable to get working. I couldn't figure out where to put it to get it to typecheck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`runNoLoggingT` has the type

```
runNoLoggingT :: NoLoggingT m a -> m a
```

and it's a valid `MonadLogger` so long as `m` above is an instance of `MonadIO`. All of the following stacks are instances of `MonadIO`

```
SqlPersist (ResourceT IO)
            ResourceT IO
                      IO
```

So all of the following stacks are valid instances of `MonadLogger`

```
NoLoggingT (SqlPersist (ResourceT IO))
SqlPersist (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO))
SqlPersist (ResourceT (NoLoggingT IO))
```

I'd recommend the third, then we just edit

```
runDb :: SqlPersist (ResourceT (NoLoggingT IO)) a -> IO a
runDb = runNoLoggingT 
      . runResourceT 
      . withSqliteConn "dev.app.sqlite3" 
      . runSqlConn
```

Comment: you have to wrap the value in a NoLoggingT constructor somewhere I guess